# python request API MultiThreading

Tags: python

I want to run this code with MultiThread. Can you help me?

```
import requests

with open("data_blocks.json","w") as file:

 for i in range(1,26000000):

     headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
     }

     params = (
        ('blockNum', i),
     )

     response = requests.get('https://xapi.esteem.app/get_block', headers=headers, params=params)
     data= response.json()
     file.write(data)
     file.write('\n')
```

Comment: If `python3+`, then https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: Also `json.dump(file)` instead of `file.write(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy).
This is an abstraction that manages a pool of threads, and to which you can ask to dispatch a batch of operations over these threads, typically through `Pool.map` and `Pool.starmap`.

You'll need to wrap the part you want to distribute inside a function, so that it can be passed to `Pool.map`.
An straightforward implementation based upon your code would look something like that:

```
from multiprocessing import dummy as mp_dummy

import requests


with open("data_blocks.json","w") as file:
    def do_one(i):
        print(f"Doing {i}")

        headers = {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        }

        params = (
          ('blockNum', i),
        )

        response = requests.get('https://xapi.esteem.app/get_block', headers=headers, params=params)
        data= response.json()
        file.write(data)
        file.write('\n')

    with mp_dummy.Pool(16) as pool:
        pool.map(do_one, range(1,26000000))
```

The `16` in `Pool(16)` means that you want to use 16 threads simultaneously.
You'll want to make this figure match the number of simultaneous connections the server accepts.

Now you could improve that implementation by passing `file` to `do_one` as an argument instead of using it as a global variable, but then you'll need to use either `Pool.starmap` or `functools.partial`:

```
import functools


def do_one(file, i):
   # Same code as above

with open("data_blocks.json", "w") as file:
    task = functools.partial(do_one, file)
    with mp_dummy.Pool(16) as pool:
        pool.map(task, range(1,26000000))
```